# Python: Bytes to string with accented characters

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, python-2.x

I have `git` reading the file name "ùàèòùèòùùè.txt" as a simple string of bytes, so when I ask git for a list of commited files, I'm given the following string:

```
r"\303\271\303\240\303\250\303\262\303\271\303\250\303\262\303\271\303\271\303\250.txt"
```

How can I use Python **2** to have it back to "ùàèòùèòùùè.txt"?

Comment: Please specify whether you are using Python 2 or 3, this is one of the main differences between them.

Comment: How did you manage to end up with ùàèòùèòùùè.txt in your file system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `git` format contains literal `\ddd` sequences (so up to 4 characters per filename byte) you can use the `string_escape` (Python 2) or `unicode_escape` (Python 3) codecs to have Python interpret the escape sequences.

You'll get UTF-8 data; my terminal is set to interpret UTF-8 directly:

```
>>> git_data = r"\303\271\303\240\303\250\303\262\303\271\303\250\303\262\303\271\303\271\303\250.txt"
>>> git_data.decode('string_escape')
'\xc3\xb9\xc3\xa0\xc3\xa8\xc3\xb2\xc3\xb9\xc3\xa8\xc3\xb2\xc3\xb9\xc3\xb9\xc3\xa8.txt'
>>> print git_data.decode('string_escape')
ùàèòùèòùùè.txt
```

You'd want to decode that as UTF-8 to get text:

```
>>> git_data.decode('string_escape').decode('utf8')
u'\xf9\xe0\xe8\xf2\xf9\xe8\xf2\xf9\xf9\xe8.txt'
>>> print git_data.decode('string_escape').decode('utf8')
ùàèòùèòùùè.txt
```

In Python 3, the `unicode_escape` codec gives you (Unicode) text so an extra encode to Latin-1 is required to make it bytes again:

```
>>> git_data = rb"\303\271\303\240\303\250\303\262\303\271\303\250\303\262\303\271\303\271\303\250.txt"
>>> git_data.decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
'ùàèòùèòùùè.txt'
```

Note that `git_data` is a `bytes` object before decoding.

Comment: Or just `print` the string

Comment: Hi, thanks! This seems to work, but the problem is that I don't need to print it, I have to set it in a string variable

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: that only works when *copying the string into Python*. This is not a literal, this is read from a file.

Comment: @pistacchio: the prints are there to demonstrate that the data has been decoded correctly.

Comment: @pistacchio: in other words: `text = git_data.decode('string_escape').decode('utf8')` gives you the Unicode text value for the given data.